# Vue based Telegram Web App opens page outside of Vue path in Browser

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a Vue-based Telegram Web App (API 6.x), which opens in Telegram App, clicking on the for Bot defined Button.

Now inside of the (one page, no router) Vue app I need to bring user to another, non-vue-based page.

Vue App > domain.com/game
Link to > domain.com/game/win

```
    // inside vue component
    <button @click="participate()">Participate Winning Game</button>
    <a href="/game/win">Participate Winning Game</a>
```

As soon the User clicks on the link (or I do in participate() window.location.href/replace), Telegram asks the user to open /gam/win in Browser.
Is there a way to avoid this behavior and load /game/win inside the Telegram App?

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I faced the same problem. Telegram Web App for Bot suggests opening any links in an external browser. I did not find documentation on the work of links in the application.

In my application on JS, I implemented a page redraw with new data received from the backend.

P.S. links to phones or other messengers like

```
<a href="tel:+79101234567">Telephone</a>
<a href="skype:test123">Skype</a>
```

do not work at all.